# Unable to connect to remote PostgreSQL server in Azure Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, azure-databricks

Error when trying to connect using psycopg2
[image: Error when trying to connect using psycopg2]
I'm able to connect to the database from my local machine using the same Python code (works instantly).

Error when trying to connect using cluster terminal using "psql" command
[image: Error when trying to connect using cluster terminal]

How can I debug what is causing the error and resolve it?

Comment: Don't post text as images of text

Comment: Could you check if the Databricks cluster you are using is able to reach the database server?  Maybe a simple ping command can help (`%sh` and `ping your_server_id`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.